# Add feature ID to NDVI timseries in GEE

Tags: export, ndvi, propertyname, feature-id

I have calculated NDVI timeseries for multiple points. I need to export a csv file that has the NDVI values, Date and ID or coordinates of points. The following script provides both the NDVI values and dates but there is no way of knowing which points those values belong to?
Any help in trying to add the feature ID:

Code as follows:

```
    // Function to remove cloud and snow pixels
function maskCloudAndShadows(image) {
  var cloudProb = image.select('MSK_CLDPRB');
  var snowProb = image.select('MSK_SNWPRB');
  var cloud = cloudProb.lt(5);
  var snow = snowProb.lt(5);
  var scl = image.select('SCL'); 
  var shadow = scl.eq(3); // 3 = cloud shadow
  var cirrus = scl.eq(10); // 10 = cirrus
  // Cloud probability less than 5% or cloud shadow classification
  var mask = (cloud.and(snow)).and(cirrus.neq(1)).and(shadow.neq(1));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

// Adding a NDVI band
function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
  return image.addBands([ndvi])
}
  
  
var startDate = '2015-08-01'
var endDate = '2023-09-01'

// Use Sentinel-2 L2A data - which has better cloud masking
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .map(maskCloudAndShadows)
    .map(addNDVI)
    .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(tree_pts))
    
// View the median composite
var vizParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 2000}
// Map.addLayer(collection.median(), vizParams, 'collection')

// var testPoint = ee.Feature(tree_pts.first())
               
 
var filteredCollection = collection.select('ndvi')
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(tree_pts.geometry()))
  
var timeSeries = ee.FeatureCollection(filteredCollection.map(function(image) {
  var stats = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: tree_pts.geometry(),
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e10
  })
  
  // reduceRegion doesn't return any output if the image doesn't intersect
  // with the point or if the image is masked out due to cloud
  // If there was no ndvi value found, we set the ndvi to a NoData value -9999
  var ndvi = ee.List([stats.get('ndvi'), -9999])
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
 
  // Create a feature with null geometry and NDVI value and date as properties
  var f = ee.Feature(null, {'ndvi': ndvi,
    'date': ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'),
    //'id'  : ee.List(image.get('system:index'))
  })
  return f
}))

 
// // Check the results
// // print(timeSeries.first())
 
// Export to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: timeSeries,
    description: 'tree_NDVI_time_series',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You code worked in my case when I uncommented `//'id'  : ee.List(image.get('system:index'))` this line. As your featurecollection is converted from an Image collection, GEE saved it as like as an image. As a result the `system:index` don't produce a single unique integer.

Btw, you can export your necessary data in a csv file along with that `id` of image. As every image is saved with a unique long text, after exporting, you will be able to sort the `CSV` file and add another column by giving an `ID` in `integer`.

Furthermore, I have edited your code to export the `CSV` file. You can copy and try it.

```
    // Create a feature with null geometry and NDVI value and date as properties
  var f = ee.Feature(null, {'ndvi': ndvi,
    'date': ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'),
    'id'  : ee.List(image.get('system:index'))
  })

  return f 
}))
print(timeSeries)


// // Check the results
print(timeSeries.first())
 
// Export to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: timeSeries,
    selectors: ["ID", "ndvi","date"],
    description: 'tree_NDVI_time_series',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})
```